# How to config consul cluster in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-consul

If there is only one consul node, it can config consul like following:

spring:

cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500

But if there is consul cluster, for example there are three concul nodes.
in this case, how to config the consul?
Do it need DNS to route the host name to multi IP address?

Answer (score 1):

you should run a consul agent in client mode on a node and join consul cluster.
then run your spring boot instance on this node and connect to this consul agent.

Comment: each consul agent  run independence with services. You should not do that